# How can you manually inject route resolve data inside a controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 routes that share a controller, one needs data resolved prior to the view loading, and the other does not need the resolved data.

Routing segment example:

```
...
when('/users', {
    controller: 'UsersCtrl',
    templateUrl: '/partials/users/view.html',
    resolve: {
        resolvedData : ['Accounts', function(Accounts) {
            return Accounts.get();
        }]
    }
}).
when('/users/add', {
    controller: 'UsersCtrl',
    templateUrl: '/partials/users/add.html'
})
...
```

Controller example:

```
app.controller('UsersCtrl', ['$scope', 'Helper', 'resolvedData', 
    function($scope, Helper, resolvedData) {
        // this works for the first route, but fails for the second route with
        // unknown "resolvedDataProvider"
        console.log(resolvedData); 
}]);
```

Is there any way I can get the `resolvedData` in the controller without explicitly using the resolve name as a dependency? So a check can be performed?

Using the $injector does not work. I would like to do something similar to:

```
if ($injector.has('resolveData')) { 
     var resolveData = $injector.get('resolveData');
}
```

However this does not work even for the route that has the `resolveData` set ('/users'):

```
app.controller('UsersCtrl', ['$scope', 'Helper', '$injector', 
    function($scope, Helper, $injector) {
        // this does not work -> fails with the unknown "resolvedDataProvider" as well
        $injector.get('resolvedData');
}]);
```

Can this be done in angularjs? Or should I just create a new controller?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like I figured out another way to go. The resolved data is part of the `$route`. So you can access it using:

```
app.controller('UsersCtrl', ['$scope', '$route', 'Helper', 
    function($scope, $route, Helper) {

        if ($route.current.locals.resolvedData) {
            var resolvedData = $route.current.locals.resolvedData;
        }
}]);
```

Comment: How is this solution better than mine? You are essentially doing the exact same thing except using a buried object in the route service to complete it. My solution allows for router uniformity and for the controller to still handle the situation.

Comment: @Fourth - I don't believe adding an unused resolve returning undefined to the route is a better option, let's just say my solution suits my needs better... I did upvote your answer, but I don't believe your downvote to mine is justified.

Comment: You are not using the features of angular in their intended way. While you have surely found a "working" answer, it does not use the features in their intended way. Route resolves are the way to inject components into your controller. Those components can, legitimately, be undefined if the resolve doesn't make sense for that route. I downvoted you to discourage others from using this solution, which is justified.

Comment: @Fourth - We'll just have to agree to disagree. The locals property of the $route is listed in the documentation and it clearly states that it contains the resolved data for that route, so it's not just something that I found and "works". http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$route

Comment: Right. The route locals has what is going to be injected on the controller during resolution. You are doing the exact same thing my code does, but you are doing it in a way that avoids router resolves because... why? You don't like returning undefined?

Comment: Because I find that approach cleaner. I'm not adding code that does nothing, given I can access my data without having to do that.

Answer (score 5):

If the other route doesn't need it, just inject undefined on that route:

router:

```
when('/users', {
    controller: 'UsersCtrl',
    templateUrl: '/partials/users/view.html',
    resolve: {
        resolvedData : ['Accounts', function(Accounts) {
            return Accounts.get();
        }]
    }
}).
when('/users/add', {
    controller: 'UsersCtrl',
    templateUrl: '/partials/users/add.html',
    resolve: {
       resolvedData: function() {
          return undefined;
       }
    }
})
```

controller:

```
app.controller('UsersCtrl', ['$scope', 'Helper', 'resolvedData', 
    function($scope, Helper, resolvedData) {
        if(resolvedData){
          //set some scope stuff for it
        } else {
         //do what you do when there is no resolvedData
        }
}]);
```